# Dell Inspiron 3551 Unresponsive Touchpad

Tags: mouse, dell, touchpad, inspiron

I just got my laptop in the mail and I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. It all went smooth until it booted up and I noticed my touch pad doesn’t work at all. It works perfectly on Windows and when I use a wireless mouse it works as well.

Here's my xinput:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]  
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                    id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎜   ↳ 2.4GHz RF  KEYBOARD  AND  MOUSE               id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎜   ↳ DLL06AB:00 06CB:78F1                          id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                    id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]  
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard                   id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Power Button                                  id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Video Bus                                     id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Power Button                                  id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Sleep Button                                  id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ 2.4GHz RF  KEYBOARD  AND  MOUSE               id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard                  id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                              id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I would love to have my track pad working and I've done some googling and browsing of this site and nothing I've tried has worked. Any input would be great. Let me know if there’s any other information that can help remedy this. I'm pretty new to Linux.
Thank you very much.

Edit: I've updated the kernel to 3.19 and checked my Additional Drivers which had nothing for me. Neither of which worked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dell Inspiron 7347 - Inactive cursor with my touchpad on UBUNTU 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/623598/dell-inspiron-7347-inactive-cursor-with-my-touchpad-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 19):

You can fix it by switching off `i2c_hid`  and setting nopnp in boot parameters this way

1. Run

   `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub`

   In the open window edit line

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
   ```

   it should look this way

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.nopnp"
   ```

   Save file and run

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
2. Run

   ```
   echo "blacklist i2c_hid" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/i2c-hid.conf
   sudo depmod -a
   sudo update-initramfs -u
   echo "synaptics_i2c" | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
   ```
3. Reboot.

Comment: I got my 3551 with 14.04, which I upgraded to 14.10. The touchpad worked fine with both. However, I upgraded to 15.04 and it stopped working. I upgraded yet again and found that it didnt work with 15.10 and kernel 4.x. The solution above fixed it for me instantly!

Comment: You are awesome @Pilot6

Comment: this resolved the problem for Dell Inspiron 13 7000 (7348) and Ubuntu 1510

Comment: Thank you very much! These commands fixed the problem. Both the touchscreen and the touchpad now work as expected.

Comment: The touchpad on my Dell Inspiron 3558 worked fine, but I was unable to disable it using `xinput disable ID` (with ID found through `xinput list`).  The above solution made everything work as desired; wonderful!

Comment: With Dell Inspiron 13 1370 the solution is a bit different. No need to blacklist i2c_hid or to add synaptics_i2c. The problem is only bound to i8042 detection at boot. The only one kernel boot parameter that is actually needed is: `i8042.reset`. No need to add `i8042.nopnp` either.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you already fixed this, but you will need to blacklist i2c-hid. So all you will need to do is open /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf as super user and add 'blacklist i2c-hid' without the quotes towards the end of the file. Reboot and your touchpad will work.

source: http://trustdarkness.com/wordpress/dell-sputnik-xps-13-touchpad-settings-not-working-in-updated-ubuntumint/

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same laptop and I had the exact same problem but i found an easy solution. Just boot on legacy mode and touchpad is working :-)

Comment: Are you talking about Legacy BIOS mode? Because there are other boot options called "legacy"…

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  ;-) Please [edit] your answer, improve it, and drop a note so that I can review my assessment of your answer, because the system flagged your answer for automatic deletion... :-(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

from the command line, enter sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
in this file are 2 'extra' repositories. Uncomment these and reboot so that your system can update available repo's. Select 'software & updates from the launcher once you are back up and running, go to the other software tab and enable the extra repositories. You should be prompted to authenticate at this stage. Next, go along to the additional drivers tab. You should find a driver that says something like 'meta package for Dell blah blah-insert-model-name-here from dino' click to enable this driver, then apply. Reboot, and you should have a fully functioning touchpad!