# Ubuntu 14.04 does not see a touchpad on my Dell Inspiron 14 3000 laptop

Tags: dell, touchpad, inspiron

Ubuntu 14.04 entirely does not see a touchpad with its buttons on my Dell Inspiron 14 3000 laptop. Re-installed Ubuntu - result is the same - no touchpad. I ran some diagnostics and here are the results:

`xinput`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:400a   id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DLL06AB:00 06CB:78F1                      id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD                      id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

`/proc/bus/input/devices`:

```
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=0007 Version=01a1
N: Name="SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input7
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event5 
B: PROP=5
B: EV=b
B: KEY=e520 610000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=660800011000003
```

`dmesg | grep -e mouse -e Mouse`:

```
[    0.873072] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    1.910005] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 8.1, id: 0x1e2a1, caps: 0xf40123/0x840300/0x12e800, board id: 3096, fw id: 1781191
[    8.856506] hid-rmi 0018:06CB:78F1.0001: input,hidraw0: <UNKNOWN> HID v1.00 Mouse [DLL06AB:00 06CB:78F1] on 
[  268.775269] logitech-djdevice 0003:046D:C52B.0005: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:400a] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1:1
```

Comment: David, thanks for advices and for help with the formatting.

Comment: I was asking for help but got that abracadabra instead. Is it a usual way to respond in this community?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dell Inspiron 3551 Unresponsive Touchpad](http://askubuntu.com/questions/592925/dell-inspiron-3551-unresponsive-touchpad)

Answer (score 4):

From: http://fr.community.dell.com/forums_daide/ordinateurs_portables_-_matriel/f/14/t/4074

> Pour votre information et si qqn est amené à requérir votre aide sur
>   le touchpad, voici comment résoudre le défaut.
>
> Ce problème se règle assez facilement, quand on sait quoi faire ! Il
>   faut ajouter une ligne à un fichier de configuration pour
>   “blacklister” un certain pilote, qui entre en conflit avec la
>   reconnaissance du touchpad. La procédure est simple, il suffit
>   d'ouvrir le Terminal (depuis le menu Unity, taper “terminal” pour
>   retrouver l'application et la lancer) et de copier-coller la commande
>   suivante (évidemment, appuyer sur Entrée ensuite)

In terminal, run:

```
echo "blacklist i2c_hid" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Then restart and the touchpad should work properly.

Comment: I can confirm that this works with Ubuntu 14.04.1. I don't know why someone else down voted it.