# Can not blacklist kernel modules in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: drivers, kernel, touchpad, 15.10

I installed Ubuntu 15.10. My [touchpad works in I2C bus AND PS2 mode](https://askubuntu.com/q/680523/338915).

I want to blacklist the I2C mode. On Ubuntu 14.04/15.04 I executed :

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

I added the following line at the end :

```
blacklist i2c_hid
```

---

But this does not work on Ubuntu 15.10 anymore.

Blacklisting other modules (like `psmouse` for example) does not work either. Am I missing something ?

Is the process of blacklisting kernel modules in Ubuntu 15.10 (kernel 4.2) different now ?

Comment: You need `i8042.nopnp` boot parameter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dell Inspiron 3551 Unresponsive Touchpad](http://askubuntu.com/questions/592925/dell-inspiron-3551-unresponsive-touchpad)

Comment: And also you may need to run `sudo update-initramfs -u`

Comment: @Pilot6 Please remove the close vote. This is not a duplicate but a general question with a specific example.

Comment: Thx to remind. I upvoted it but forgot to remove the close vote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This module must be in `initramfs`. To get it blacklisted run:

```
sudo depmod -a
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Comment: That worked, is there a way to undo this change ?

Comment: Remove that blacklist entry and run the commands again.

Comment: I did... Can't get the I2C mode back... Can it be related to the `libinput` install?

Comment: No. Libinput is a user space driver. It is not related to kernel modules. Maybe remove `i8042.nopnp` and run `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: Yes I did too...

Comment: And also `grep i2c_hid /etc/modprobe.d/*`

Comment: `sudo modprobe i2c_hid` output nothing

Comment: You could blacklist it somewhere else. Run the grep command and you will find it.

Comment: Ok got it.  `sudo modprobe i2c_hid` get it back. Thanks !

Comment: Or a reboot. I did not mention it.