# Touch pad not working Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, touchpad

Touch pad stopped working after installing Ubuntu 14.04 while it was working on Windows 8.

I tried to install by using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptics
```

it displays the message:

```
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics is already the newest version.
```

I have a dell inspiron 3451 laptop

Please suggest.

Comment: What is your hardware?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/592925/dell-inspiron-3551-unresponsive-touchpad/632570?s=1|1.5510#632570

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the touchpad and then re-install.  Sometimes that fixes issues like that.

See if it's listed on xinput with

```
xinput list
```

If it is, check to see if it's enabled or not.
If it's not on the list, then uninstalling and reinstalling the drivers with apt-get seems to be the best option, given I don't know your hardware specs.

What laptop do you have, and what type of touchpad?

Comment: Well when  I type :  xinput list  , it shows : 
↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad               id=14 [slave  pointer  (2)]

Comment: @LorWem That means the device is recognized, but it's not working properly.  Try uninstalling and reinstalling the drivers for it if you're having any issues.  [If you just want to temporarily disable it, you can do xinput disable 14, and then it'll be disabled until you restart your system.]