# Asus K751LJ-TY316T touchpad not detected / working under Ubuntu 14.04.3

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, asus

There is no "touch-pad" section in system settings->mouse and touch-pad.
<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> just shows a crossed out touch-pad symbol.

Please help; THX!

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]  
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎜   ↳ HID 04b4:0033                             id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]  
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ USB Camera                                id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]  
[    2.062714] pnp: PnP ACPI init  
[    2.062962] pnp 00:01: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs SYN0a2d SYN0a00 SYN0002 PNP0f13 (active)
[    2.062997] pnp 00:02: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs ATK3001 PNP030b (active)  
[    2.063121] pnp 00:04: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0b00 (active)  
[    2.064110] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 8 devices  
3.19.0-46-generic
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput; dmesg | grep pnp; uname -r` terminal command.

Comment: This is something new. I did not see this type of a touchpad on asus. You may try to switch to `synaptics_i2c` as directed http://askubuntu.com/a/632570/167850

Comment: I ran the commands, modified the file and rebooted; nothing...

Comment: Try kernel 4.4.

Comment: I ran these commands and got "system problem detected"                                                                                                                                   cd /tmp/

wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4-wily/linux-headers-4.4.0-040400_4.4.0-040400.201601101930_all.deb

wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4-wily/linux-headers-4.4.0-040400-generic_4.4.0-040400.201601101930_amd64.deb

wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4-wily/linux-image-4.4.0-040400-generic_4.4.0-040400.201601101930_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i *.deb

Comment: DId I damage anything? Could you please give me a step-by-step instruction how to install kernel 4.4? Im a n00b...