# How to enable touchpad, without changing touchpad settings in BIOS to basic

Tags: touchpad, synaptics

I tried a lot to make touchpad enable in Ubuntu 16.04.1. I reinstalled drivers, kernals, was using synclient(as a matter of fact it has never changed "TouchpadOff" option), dconf. The only thing that helped me is setting inside of BIOS(or in my case UEFI) touchpad option to "Basic".

But I've got dual booting Ubuntu-Win10 and using Windows with "Basic" option isn't satisfying.

So the question: how to enable touchpad without changing BIOS's options?

**UPD:**

Cannot set this option in synclient setting also:

```
 synclient | grep Touchpad
    TouchpadOff             = 2
 synclient Touchpadoff=0 
 synclient | grep Touchpad
    TouchpadOff             = 0
 synclient | grep Touchpad
    TouchpadOff             = 2
```

`xinput`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                id=2     [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer      id=4     [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ A4TECH USB Device               id=12    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ A4TECH USB Device               id=13    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad         id=15    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard               id=3     [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard     id=5     [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                    id=6     [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                       id=7     [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                       id=8     [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                    id=9     [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                    id=10    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HD WebCam                       id=11    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard    id=14    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Acer WMI hotkeys                id=16    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

`xinput list-props`:

```
Device 'PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
    Device Enabled (137):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (139): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (263): 0
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (264):   1.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (265):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (266):    10.000000
    Device Product ID (257):    2, 1
    Device Node (258):  "/dev/input/event9"
    Evdev Axis Inversion (267): 0, 0
    Evdev Axes Swap (269):  0
    Axis Labels (270):  "Rel X" (147), "Rel Y" (148)
    Button Labels (271):    "Button Left" (140), "Button Middle" (141), "Button Right" (142), "Button Wheel Up" (143), "Button Wheel Down" (144)
    Evdev Scrolling Distance (272): 0, 0, 0
    Evdev Middle Button Emulation (273):    0
    Evdev Middle Button Timeout (274):  50
    Evdev Third Button Emulation (275): 0
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Timeout (276): 1000
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Button (277):  3
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (278):   20
    Evdev Wheel Emulation (279):    0
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (280):   0, 0, 4, 5
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (281):    10
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (282):    200
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (283): 4
    Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (284):  0
```

Comment: What is the touchpad, what is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: @Pilot6 SYN1B81:01 06CB:7407 Touchpad

Comment: Try this http://askubuntu.com/a/632570/167850

Comment: @Pilot6 Okay, now my touchpad is working, but drivers are gone and no touchpad feature is working. I've already tried reinstalling them, but nothing changed

Comment: What drivers are you talking about?

Comment: @pilot6 synaptic

Comment: It is not clear at all. How do you install "drivers"? And `synaptic` is not a touchpad driver at all. You probably broke the system somehow before.

Comment: What features are you asking about? Did you install libinput? It sould disable synclient.

Comment: Now I can only use touchpad as a mouse; nothing like scrolling is able. Also tochpad disappeared from mouse settings

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` command.

Comment: Please add output of `xinput list-props 15`. It looks like the touchpad is now in PS/2 mode only. Let's see.

Comment: Run `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-all` then reboot and test.

Comment: @Pilot6 didn't help

Comment: Did anything install?

Comment: If `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` is installed, then it looks like the touchpad is not fully supported by this kernel.

Comment: `xserver-xorg-input-all` is installed, your question is about sth else?

Comment: This must be a new touchpad only partially supported. You may need a newer kernel. But no guarantee.

Comment: @pilot6 okay, thanks a lot. Should I deleted the question?

Comment: Leave the question as is. maybe someone already tried another kernel, etc.

Comment: @Pilot6 Well, I installed Xubuntu 16, made everything like in your answer to the askubuntu.com/a/632570/167850 and now everything works fine. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I have become extremely annoyed at the touchpad changing my cursor position as I try to type, so I've searched all over the internet just to try and disable it. I have Linux Mint 18 installed with kernel 4.4.0-45. I did the following to make it easy to toggle the touchpad state.

`sudo apt-get install xinput`

`xinput -list`

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse          id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ FTE1001:00 0B05:0101                      id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

- Look for the id of the touchpad, in my case it's 14. I wrote a small shell script to turn the touchpad off and on.
- TouchPad off:

  `cd /usr/local/bin`
  `sudo nano touchpad-off`

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  xinput --set-prop 14 "Device Enabled" 0
  echo touchpad off
  ```
- TouchPad on:

  `sudo nano touchpad-on`

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  xinput --set-prop 14 "Device Enabled" 1
  echo touchpad on
  ```
- Make the scripts executable with:

  ```
  chmod +x touchpad-off
  chmod +x touchpad-on
  ```

  Now you can easily toggle the touchpad state with `touchpad-off` and `touchpad-on`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no approved answer, although the problem seems solved for the original poster. I think we should try to clean this up for users in the future who find this note.

I wonder if the libinput driver's upgrades are responsible for the improvement here, rather than synaptics driver. What does "synclient -l" return on the fixed system?  If it says "Couldn't find synaptics properties" then we'll know the fix is coming from libinput. In Ubuntu 16.10, there are quite a few more laptop profiles included with libinput.

If it is synaptics, well, I'm baffled why this would improve.