# No mouse or network after install

Tags: networking, 16.04, mouse, dell

I downloaded Ubuntu version 16.04, created a bootable usbdisk from the ISO, and booted up my Dell Latitude E6420 laptop without installing anything. The desktop worked fine, both mouse/mousepad and network. 
After that when I installed it on to the harddrive, the mouse and network does not work. The system can not find either mouse, mousepad or network.

I have tried to install it several times, and Kubuntu 16.04 as well. I even installed version 15.10, same result. Every install fails to deliver mouse and network on my pc. I then installed it on a Dell Optiplex 990, same result.

The weird part is that when I boot the pc with the usbstick, everything works fine.

Has anyone else seen this behavior or had trouble with Dell Computers and later versions of Ubuntu?

This is not a duplicate of the question in "[Dell Inspiron 3551 Unresponsive Touchpad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/592925)" as this is not limited to the mousepad, but also applies to plugged in mouse, networkcard (both cable and wifi).

I have tried the solution in the question on the 15.10 installation, and it did not work. 
I got the following error when trying the command sudo depmod -a:

- depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/3.13.0-43-generic: No such file or directory

  - depmod: ERROR: could not search modules: No such file or directory.

UPDATE: I have now reinstalled version 16.04, and found that when I do a uname -r command, it reports version 3.13, not 4.4. I cannot find /var/log/messages either. Could this be a kernel issue with version 4.4 and Dell, and then falls back to an earlier version?

I have tried to force it to load 4.4, but it does not comply. Any ideas to what can be done to sort this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dell Inspiron 3551 Unresponsive Touchpad](http://askubuntu.com/questions/592925/dell-inspiron-3551-unresponsive-touchpad)