# ubuntu 16.04 upgrade - two finger scroll not working

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, touchpad, dell

Some months ago I did a Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 upgrade on my Dell Inspiron - 5000 series.

After performing the upgrade I noticed the two finger scroll is not working any more. The option in the settings menu is available and active but the two finger scroll does not work. The other mouse functions on the touchpad work though.
Previous questions on this forum did not result in a solution.

Does somebody has some experience concerning this matter?
I would love to use my two finger scroll again

thanks

output of xinput terminal command:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DLLC6AD:00 06CB:75BF Touchpad             id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                   id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD                      id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ DELL Wireless hotkeys                     id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.

Comment: I edited the output, hopefully it can be of some use, thanks!

Comment: If you hold your fingers a bit apart, does it work?

Comment: fingers holding apart didn't work also solution on http://askubuntu.com/questions/592925/dell-inspiron-3551-unresponsive-touchpad don't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Although I use a wireless mouse, I also upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04 on a Dell Inspiron 17R 7720 SE and the two finger scrolling works perfectly (I just tried it). I'm on Kernel version 4.7.5 with Intel microcode updates though and never tested under Kernel 4.4. I just want to let you know it does work on Dell touchpad under 16.04.

There is a screen you need to go to in `System Settings`, `Mouse & Touchpad` to enable `two-finger scrolling` as this screen snapshot illustrates:

[image: Two Finger Scrolling]

---

### Edit 1 - Synaptics Driver Override

Having verified that `Two finger scroll` is checked and it still doesn't work, we need to dig deeper. Read [wiki.debian.org/SynapticsTouchpad](https://wiki.debian.org/SynapticsTouchpad). Where it says:

If **multitouch** doesn't work for you, your hardware may not support it, but you can use the following options to emulate multitouch which allows most of the features to work. Try adding these lines to the `Touchpad` section:

```
Option          "EmulateTwoFingerMinZ"  "35"
Option          "EmulateTwoFingerMinW"  "8"
```

Follow the instructions in the link

Comment: Hello, these settings have been checked and are all activated. However no 2 finger scroll.

Comment: Maybe uncheck 'natural scrolling'? I can't test now because I'm on phone.

Comment: unfortunately unchecking 'natural scrolling' wasn't the solution

Comment: @Bramb I updated the answer with the next step to try.