# Two finger scrolling not working in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mouse, touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics

I recently reinstalled Ubuntu to find two finger scrolling in my touchpad was no longer working. I came across [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/832356/ubuntu-16-04-upgrade-two-finger-scroll-not-working) post and it shows that I should be having that option in my system settings. However, my mouse and trackpad settings look like this

[image]As you can see, I am missing those options. I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372988/enable-both-two-finger-scrolling-and-edge-scrolling-permanently) and similar posts for other versions on Ubuntu but not for 16.04. How do I do this?

Comment: Had similar problem. Try this <https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-tweak-tool/+bug/1492217>.