# Which ID belongs to the touchpad?

Tags: touchpad

I want to disable the middle mouse button in my touchpad, but I don't know which one is the actual touchpad. Is it 11 or 13?

```
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DLLC6B2:00 06CB:75BF Touchpad             id=11   [slave  pointer(2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/592925/dell-inspiron-3551-unresponsive-touchpad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This touchpad supports both PS/2 and I2C modes. So both IDs are related to the touchpad.

If the system is configured correctly, I2C should be in use. But in some cases it needs configuration.

The easiest way to check is to run `xinput disable 11` and `xinput disable 13` the command that disables the touchpad will show you the correct ID.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to disable the middle mouse button. But after I restarted it started working again. How do I permanently disable it?

Comment: You can ask another question. It depends on a few things.