# Why does the XPS 9550 touchpad stop working sporadically?

Tags: unity, 17.04, synaptics, libinput

Running Ubuntu 17.04 with kernel 4.11.12.
I have a thread ([thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2367880&p=13672725#post13672725)) over at UbuntuForums and I've been searching for a fix for two days now. Working just fine just after login the tap to click function and scrolling stops working on the touchpad sporadically, but the cursor remains active and usable. So does the physical clicks. It doesn't happen in Windows and it didn't happen before in Ubuntu so I know it's not faulty hardware. Don't know what could have caused it. Highly annoying since it renders the laptop worthless in a lot of cases if I can't scroll or use my preferred way of click input.

On top of my head I'm wondering if this could be a bug in the desktop manager? Unity in this case.

Comment: Does it work well with a supported Ubuntu kernel?

Comment: I believe it used to work w/o issues on 4.10 and that's what 17.04 is based on right? I only recently updated to 4.11.12 from the mainline PPA trying to resolve the issue.

Comment: If the touchpad works on 4.10 and doesn't on 4.11, the question is off-topic here.

Comment: I updated to 4.11 trying to fix it since it started happening on 4.10.

Comment: I just noticed something interesting. In an attempt to fix it I removed the package xserver-xorg-input-libinput and then re-installed it. Before I removed it running cat /proc/bus/input/devices did NOT show an input for the Synaptics Touchpad. Only DLL06E4:01 06CB:7A13 Touchpad. Now cat /proc/bus/input/devices DOES show an entry for both. Could this have been the issue?

Comment: See this https://askubuntu.com/a/632570/167850

Comment: That's for a touchpad that doesn't work at all though. Mine works perfectly a while after I login, but then only tapping and scrolling stops working. On a side note. Ever since I re-installed libinput I haven't had the issue yet. Usually didn't take more than ~15 min for it to stop working properly before.

Comment: The problem just occurred and looking at the printout from "cat /proc/bus/input/devices" the entry for the Synaptics Touchpad is now gone.

Comment: Would love to know what could be causing this. Now after having removed the code that disabled one of two touchpads in synaptics-quirks.conf xinput only lists one of them. At first it listed both and the cat /proc/bus/input/devices only shows one as well.