# How do I debug a detected but not working trackpad?

Tags: 18.04, touchpad

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS on a Dell laptop with a built-in trackpad.  All of a sudden, the trackpad has stopped working.

It is detected, but not sending any events.

`xinput` lists:

`⎜   ↳ Synaptics TM3096-001                     id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]`

Also, `gnome-settings` detects it, and I can change its options either via settings or xinput.  But nothing has any actual effect.

I installed `evtest` and when I run that on the correct input event, it listens to events but none occur.

I've tried everything I've read about here - reloading certain kernel modules, disabling and reenabling the trackpad via `xinput`.  There isn't a BIOS option for it, so I haven't been able to try switching it from "Advanced" to "Basic".

I'm not sure where to go with this, hence my question: how do I debug this?  The similar solutions I've read usually involve not detecting a trackpad, or some feature not working.  I've not found anything where the trackpad is detected but no events are being sent.

*Edit:* `uname -a` returns:

```
~% uname -a
Linux Xxxxxx 4.15.0-72-generic #81-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 26 12:20:02 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Which kernel `uname -a`

Comment: @nobody Added in - what else would be useful to know to help?

Comment: Thanks to the "Related questions" list, I've tracked down a solution at https://askubuntu.com/a/632570/6684 - happy to either close this question as no-longer-relevant or a duplicate of that.